# How could i parse out and count up distinct list in Excel?

Tags: excel, list, vba

I have an excel column that looks like this:

Person 1, Person 2
Person 3
Person 4
Person 5
Person 1
Person 1, Person 4

So in each cell, there is either a single person or a list of people.  I want to count these up to be able to generate a count of each person like this from the structure above

Person 1: 3
Person 2: 1
Person 3: 1
Person 4: 2
Person 5: 1

Is there any good way of doing this in VBA?

Comment: Please add to your post: 1. what you're trying, and 2. any error you're getting. Thank you.

Comment: On the last row in your example should there be a comma between "Person 1" and the next "Person 1"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use this you'll need to add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime (for the Dictionary object)

```
Sub countU()

Dim c As Range
Dim s As String, v As Variant, i As Integer
Dim arr() As String
Dim dic As Dictionary
Set dic = New Dictionary

'call your actual range here 
For Each c In ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A5")
    s = c.Value
    s = Replace(s, "Person", "")
    s = Replace(s, " ", "")
    arr = Split(s, ",")

    For Each v In arr
        If dic.Exists(v) Then
            dic.Item(v) = dic.Item(v) + 1
        Else
            dic.Add v, 1
        End If

    Next v
Next c

For Each strKey In dic.Keys()
    'output to your desired location here
    Debug.Print "Person " & strKey & ": " & dic.Item(strKey)

Next strKey


End Sub
```

What might be an improvement on this is making it a function accepting a range (your range to iterate over (what I am calling A1:A5 in my sample) then set the out put of the function to a range populated with your discovered values.

Answer (score 0):

This will work if all your cells contain only one person, and you can achieve this by going to Data > Text to Columns, selecting Delimited, and checking comma. In the case where people aren't separated by a comma, you would need a way to separate them.

Use a two dimensional array, storing the person in the first dimension and the count in the second dimension of each element. Loop through the cells that contains your list, and using Mid(), check to see if that cell has a substring equal to any of the strings in the first dimension in your array. If it does, increase the count of that element by 1.

Answer (score 0):

In VBA look into the split() function.

Loop through your rows, and do

array() = split("cell string", ",")

split returns an array of strings you can then loop through and count.

Hope this helps you get on the right track.